# Индексация поисковиками страниц

Tags: seo, индексация, раскрутка

Новичок в seo,вопрос такой. Готовится сайт где будут статьи,каждая статья будет иметь ссылку вида "домен.ru/detail?id=1233". Все ли страницы со статьями рано или поздно будут индексироваться поисковиками? И если планируется удалять безвозратно статьи старее пол года, из за актуальности, получается в поисковике эти индексы могут остаться и человек перейдя на удаленную статью попадет на 404?

Answer (score 1):

Как уже написал Vladislav Belozerov в своём ответе, все статьи будут когда-то проиндексированы (но не обязательно будут показываться в поиске, это отдельный вопрос). Лучше всего чтобы все эти страницы были в каком-то меню, доступном с главной страницы или с внутренних разделов. Если страница вообще нигде не указана в навигации сайта, то тогда остаётся только делать sitemap. Когда вы удалите страницы, то через какое-то время (иногда долго) поисковик исключит страницу из индекса. А до этого времени будет 404. И вместо таких адресов лучше используйте ЧПУ (человеко-понятные url), они доступны в движках типа вордпресса из коробки или их можно делать самому через .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Рано или поздно то будут, чтобы ускорить процесс зарегистрируйтесь в Вебмастер-консолях Google и Яндекс и добавьте главную страницу. Сформируйте и отправьте [sitemap](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=ru), настройте [robots.txt](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062596?hl=ru), проверяйте страницы на наличие ошибок(через Lighthouse в средствах разработчика Chrome).

Поисковики постараются исключить ваши битые ссылки, но лучше сделать это вручную через консоль.

Answer (score 0):

Позвольте мне дать мой ответ с точки зрения Гугл.

> Все ли страницы со статьями рано или поздно будут индексироваться
> поисковиками?

Гугл может не индексировать такие веб-страницы, которые имеют не оригинальное содержание, например скопированное с посторонних веб-сайтов. В Консоле Поиска может быть примерно следующее сообщение: "*УРЛ получен в карте сайта, но не индексирован*" или что-то подобное. Это связано с тем фактом, что Гугл (возможно и все поисковики) трудно определить релевантность для дублированного/копированного содержания, которое найдено на нескольких сепаратных веб-сайтах. Об этом Гугл прямого говорит в своей статье на английском языке **[Ways to succeed in Google News](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2019/01/ways-to-succeed-in-google-news.html)**:

> Повторяющийся контент   Новости Google стремятся вознаградить
> независимый оригинальный журналистский контент, отдавая должное
> исходному издателю, как того пожелают и пользователи, и издатели. Это
> означает, что мы стараемся не допускать, чтобы дублированный контент -
> в том числе скопированный, переписанный или повторно опубликованный
> материал - работал лучше, чем исходный контент. В соответствии с этим
> издателям следует соблюдать следующие правила:
>
> Блокировать извлеченный контент: под парсингом обычно подразумевается
> получение материала с другого сайта, часто автоматически. Сайты,
> которые очищают контент, должны блокировать извлеченный контент из
> Новостей Google. Блокировать перезаписанный контент: под
> переписыванием подразумевается взятие материала с другого сайта, а
> затем его переписывание таким образом, чтобы оно не было идентичным.
> Сайты, которые переписывают контент таким образом, чтобы не приносить
> существенной или очевидной добавленной стоимости, должны блокировать
> переписанный контент из Новостей Google. Это включает, но не
> ограничивается, переписывания, которые вносят лишь очень
> незначительные изменения, или те, которые содержат много замен слов,
> но при этом сохраняют общее значение исходной статьи.

Учитывая тот факт что большинство статей являются по сути новостями, это может быть полезным для ваших стаей.

Кроме того, Гугл будет внимательно определять категорию содержания ваших веб-страниц на предмет совместимости содержания с категорией **Your Money or Your Life (YMYL)** - Ваши Деньги или Ваша Жизнь. В своем руководстве (на анг. яз.) **[Search Quality Evaluator Guidelines](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/en//insidesearch/howsearchworks/assets/searchqualityevaluatorguidelines.pdf)** Гугл говорит об этом следующее:

> What webpages Google ranks as Your Money or Your Life (YMYL):
>
> Some types of pages could potentially impact the future happiness,
> health, financial stability, or safety of users. We call such pages
> “Your Money or Your Life” pages, or YMYL. The following are examples
> of YMYL pages: ● Shopping or financial transaction pages: webpages
> that allow users to make purchases, transfer money, pay bills, etc.
> online (such as online stores and online banking pages). ● Financial
> information pages: webpages that provide advice or information about
> investments, taxes, retirement planning, home purchase, paying for
> college, buying insurance, etc. ● Medical information pages: webpages
> that provide advice or information about health, drugs, specific
> diseases or conditions, mental health, nutrition, etc. ● Legal
> information pages: webpages that provide legal advice or information
> on topics such as divorce, child custody, creating a will, becoming a
> citizen, etc. ● News articles or public/official information pages
> important for having an informed citizenry: webpages that include
> information about local/state/national government processes, policies,
> people, and laws; disaster response services; government programs and
> social services; news about important topics such as international
> events, business, politics, science, and technology; etc.
>
> Какие веб-страницы Google считает вашими деньгами или вашей жизнью
> (YMYL):
>
> Некоторые типы страниц могут потенциально повлиять на будущее счастье,
> здоровье, финансовую стабильность или безопасность пользователей. Мы
> называем такие страницы страницами «Ваши деньги или ваша жизнь» или
> YMYL. Ниже приведены примеры страниц YMYL: ● Страницы покупок или
> финансовых транзакций: веб-страницы, которые позволяют пользователям
> совершать покупки, переводить деньги, оплачивать счета и т. Д. В
> Интернете (например, интернет-магазины и страницы онлайн-банкинга). ●
> Страницы с финансовой информацией: веб-страницы, содержащие советы или
> информацию об инвестициях, налогах, пенсионном планировании, покупке
> дома, оплате обучения в колледже, покупке страховки и т. Д. ● Страницы
> с медицинской информацией: веб-страницы, содержащие советы или
> информацию о здоровье, лекарствах, конкретных заболеваниях или
> состояниях, психическом здоровье, питании и т. Д. ● Страницы с
> юридической информацией: веб-страницы, содержащие юридические
> консультации или информацию по таким темам, как развод, опека над
> детьми, составление завещания, получение гражданства и т. Д. ●
> Новостные статьи или публичные / официальные информационные страницы,
> важные для информирования граждан: веб-страницы, содержащие информацию
> о процессах, политике, людях и законах местного / государственного /
> национального правительства; службы реагирования на стихийные
> бедствия; государственные программы и социальные услуги; новости на
> важные темы, такие как международные события, бизнес, политика, наука
> и технологии; и т.п.

Таким образом большинство новостных веб-сайтов, веб-сайтов имеющих медицинское, финансовое и юридическое и веб-сайтов е-коммерции могут быть отнесены к категории Ваши Деньги или Ваша Жизнь. Для продвижение ваших статей в этой категории вам понадобиться создание содержания высокого уровня надежности и достоверности -  **Expertise, Authoritativeness, and Trustworthiness (E-A-T)**. Если содержание ваших статей не будет удовлетворять требования Гугл, то ваши веб-страницы могут быть индексированы, но в результатах поиска могут быть ниже 100-го или даже 400-го места. Однако это уже за пределами вашего вопроса.